# Cyanogenmod 13 brunch i9500 failed

Tags: android, android-source, cyanogenmod, android-6.0.1-marshmallow

Following the guide at https://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Build_for_i9500 to build CM 13 for Samsung S4 i9500 and `brunch i9500` command fails, here is the output

```
brunch i9500
including vendor/cm/vendorsetup.sh
Looking for dependencies

============================================
PLATFORM_VERSION_CODENAME=REL
PLATFORM_VERSION=6.0.1
CM_VERSION=13.0-20160906-UNOFFICIAL-i9500
TARGET_PRODUCT=cm_i9500
TARGET_BUILD_VARIANT=userdebug
TARGET_BUILD_TYPE=release
TARGET_BUILD_APPS=
TARGET_ARCH=arm
TARGET_ARCH_VARIANT=armv7-a-neon
TARGET_CPU_VARIANT=cortex-a15
TARGET_2ND_ARCH=
TARGET_2ND_ARCH_VARIANT=
TARGET_2ND_CPU_VARIANT=
HOST_ARCH=x86_64
HOST_OS=linux
HOST_OS_EXTRA=Linux-4.4.0-36-generic-x86_64-with-Ubuntu-16.04-xenial
HOST_BUILD_TYPE=release
BUILD_ID=MOB30Z
OUT_DIR=/home/ubuntu/android/system/out
============================================

make: Entering directory '/home/ubuntu/android/system'
============================================
"ebtables is disabled on this build"
external/sepolicy/Android.mk:22: BOARD_SEPOLICY_UNION is no longer required - all files found in BOARD_SEPOLICY_DIRS are implicitly unioned; please remove from your BoardConfig.mk or other .mk file.
build/core/base_rules.mk:559: warning: overriding recipe for target '/home/ubuntu/android/system/out/target/product/i9500/root/res/images/charger/battery_fail.png'
build/core/base_rules.mk:559: warning: ignoring old recipe for target '/home/ubuntu/android/system/out/target/product/i9500/root/res/images/charger/battery_fail.png'
find: 'dummy': No such file or directory
No private recovery resources for TARGET_DEVICE i9500
...
target Prebuilt: RobotoCondensed-Regular.ttf (/home/ubuntu/android/system/out/target/product/i9500/obj/ETC/RobotoCondensed-Regular.ttf_intermediates/RobotoCondensed-Regular.ttf)
target thumb C++: camera.universal5410 <= device/samsung/i9500/camera/CameraWrapper.cpp
target thumb C++: gralloc.default <= hardware/libhardware/modules/gralloc/framebuffer.cpp
device/samsung/i9500/camera/CameraWrapper.cpp:68:1: sorry, unimplemented: non-trivial designated initializers not supported
 };
 ^
device/samsung/i9500/camera/CameraWrapper.cpp:68:1: warning: missing initializer for member 'camera_module::init' [-Wmissing-field-initializers]
device/samsung/i9500/camera/CameraWrapper.cpp:68:1: warning: missing initializer for member 'camera_module::reserved' [-Wmissing-field-initializers]
device/samsung/i9500/camera/CameraWrapper.cpp:98:41: warning: unused parameter 'id' [-Wunused-parameter]
 static char *camera_fixup_getparams(int id, const char *settings)
                                         ^
build/core/binary.mk:730: recipe for target '/home/ubuntu/android/system/out/target/product/i9500/obj/SHARED_LIBRARIES/camera.universal5410_intermediates/CameraWrapper.o' failed
make: *** [/home/ubuntu/android/system/out/target/product/i9500/obj/SHARED_LIBRARIES/camera.universal5410_intermediates/CameraWrapper.o] Error 1
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make: Leaving directory '/home/ubuntu/android/system'
```

Any ideas how to progress?

Comment: Seems that your C++ (g++ ?) compiler can't compile `CameraWrapper.cpp`. Check your build environment, version of the compiler needs to be in line with that specified in CM13 docs.

Comment: I couldn't find CM docs mentioning any version for the compiler.  The docs just mentions installing g++-multilib without any version, which would be the latest available